# Service invoked too many times: trigger

Tags: google-apps, google-sheets, google-apps-script

We are trying to implement a suite of spreadsheets that will handle budget figures for a set of stores. Everything works fine until we try to implement a spreadsheet that will collect data from all store spreadsheets and present statistics. Due to the limitation of ImportRange, of a maximum of 50 uses per spreadsheet doc, we have been implementing a Google docs script instead to handle the importing of data. But now when we have made a copy of the document to have one for each month, we are getting problems with our time triggers. We have setup a trigger to run the script once every minute and that results in an error message stating; **Service invoked too many times: trigger**.

What are the limitations here? And how do we best solve this?

We are also getting some other error messages and would like to know how to solve these;

- Document tEHGO48zIBIFYRpb7Xhjwqg is missing (perhaps it was deleted?) (line 191)
- Exceeded maximum execution time
- Service error: Spreadsheets (line 290)

Where can we find documentation describing the different limitations and error messages?

Answer (score 1):

Quota Limits for many services used with Google Apps Scripts have now been published on the Dashboard at:

https://docs.google.com/macros/dashboard

Answer (score 0):

Just happened the same to me. It seems there is a **non-published limit**:

> Premier accounts usually have larger quotas for every limitation.
>   The argument is that the account is better verified and less likely to exploit to resources.
>
> But neither the regular limitations or Premier's better quotas are published by Google. And it seems that Googlers can't say it here in the forums either. The only well defined GAS limitation is the email quota, accessible through:
>   MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota()
>   Which is 500 for regular accounts and 1500 for Premier.
>
> *Source: [Google Support forums](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/apps-script/thread?tid=71aad4f06391210f&hl=en)*

Solutions are:

- Join several scripts into one big trigger in case there is a limit in number of triggers
- Optimize code (join loops, refresh only the necessary fields, etc.) in case it is based in CPU usage
- Move minute timer triggers to **OnEdit** or **OnOpen** triggers whenever possible
- Get a Premium Account

For your other errors, I haven't encountered any similar. You should post some details on the script or publish some code so we can debug it.